# Fastest way to fill numpy array with new arrays from function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function `f(a)` that takes one entry from a `testarray` and returns an array with 5 values:

```
f(testarray[0])
#Output: array([[0, 1, 5, 3, 2]])
```

Since `f(testarray[0])` is the result of an experiment, I want to run this function `f` for each entry of the `testarray` and store each result in a new NumPy array. I always thought this would be quite simple by just taking an empty NumPy array with the length of the `testarray` and save the results the following way:

```
N = 1000 #Number of entries of the testarray
test_result  = np.zeros([N, 5], dtype=int)

for i in testarray:
        test_result[i] = f(i)
```

When I run this, I don't receive any error message but nonsense results (half of the `test_result` is empty while the rest is filled with implausible values). Since `f()` works perfectly for a single entry of the `testarray` I suppose that something of the way of how I save the results in the `test_result` is wrong. What am I missing here?

(I know that I could save the results as list and then append an empty list, but this method is too slow for the large number of times I want to run the function).

Comment: Do you want an answer in sequence or random?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean exactly? At the end I would like to have an array of the following form:
`array([[0, 1, 4, 3, 3],
       [0, 1, 5, 3, 2],
       [0, 1, 4, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 1, 5, 3, 3],
       [0, 1, 4, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 4, 2, 0]])`

Comment: do you already have other arrays and you want to append those to a single one is it?

Comment: This should work fine if `testarray` is `np.arange(N)`.  Pay attention to what `i` is?  An argument for `f` or an index?

Comment: @hpaulj It seems the error must be due to the indexing as you said. `for i in range(len(testarray)):; test_result[i] = f(testarray[i])`

Comment: @hpaulj: Argument for `f` (because it is an element from the `testarray`)
@Ali_Sh: The `range(len(testarray))` does not work for me (`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'`)

Comment: you don't want to use elements of `testarray` as indices

Comment: I could not understand. `shape` is used?? I did not use `shape` in the code. Please put a reproducible example that help others to find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to understand indexing, stick with this approach

```
alist = [f(i) for i in testarray]
arr = np.array(alist)
```

I could show how to use row indices and testarray values together, but that requires more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may could be reproduced by the following small example:

```
testarray = np.array([5, 6, 7, 3, 1])

def f(x):
    return np.array([x * i for i in np.arange(1, 6)])

f(testarray[0])
# [ 5 10 15 20 25]

test_result = np.zeros([len(testarray), 5], dtype=int)  # len(testarray) or testarray.shape[0]
```

So, as [**hpaulj** mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), you must be careful how to use indexing:

```
for i in range(len(testarray)):
    test_result[i] = f(testarray[i])

# [[ 5 10 15 20 25]
#  [ 6 12 18 24 30]
#  [ 7 14 21 28 35]
#  [ 3  6  9 12 15]
#  [ 1  2  3  4  5]]
```

There will be another condition where the `testarray` is a specified index array that contains shuffle integers from `0` to `N` to full fill the zero array i.e. `test_result`. For this condition we can create a reproducible example as:

```
testarray = np.array([4, 3, 0, 1, 2])

def f(x):
    return np.array([x * i for i in np.arange(1, 6)])

f(testarray[0])
# [ 4  8 12 16 20]

test_result = np.zeros([len(testarray), 5], dtype=int)
```

So, using your loop will get the following result:

```
for i in testarray:
    test_result[i] = f(i)
# [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
#  [ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 2  4  6  8 10]
#  [ 3  6  9 12 15]
#  [ 4  8 12 16 20]]
```

As it can be understand from this loop, if the index array be not from `0` to  `N`, some rows in the zero array will left zero (unchanged):

```
testarray = np.array([4, 2, 4, 1, 2])

for i in testarray:
    test_result[i] = f(i)
# [[ 0  0  0  0  0]   # <--
#  [ 1  2  3  4  5]
#  [ 2  4  6  8 10]
#  [ 0  0  0  0  0]   # <--
#  [ 4  8 12 16 20]]
```